# Creating fs snapshot of database that newer mariadb can use?

Tags: mariadb

Have a large db, trying to dumb takes forever.  Previously/currently will do basically:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
mysql -u root << EOF
    FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;
    system zfs snapshot db01/mysql@cron-$(date +%Y%m%d.%H%M);
    UNLOCK TABLES;
EOF
```

And then use zfs send/recv to do incremental backups.  And we’ve used those backups before for testing.. and it was always fine.  Setup some test instance, copy some snapshot, start mariadb and it ‘just works’.  But new instance would always be same CentOS7 image with same version of mariadb, which I guess avoided some possible problems with snapshots.

But now I’m wanting to snapshot filesystem, then send fs to a system with a newer version of mariadb and it fails to start:

```
Nov 24 02:55:51 test001 mariadbd[453773]: 2022-11-24  2:55:51 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Upgrade after a crash is not supported. This redo log was created before MariaDB 10.2.2.
Nov 24 02:55:51 test001 mariadbd[453773]: 2022-11-24  2:55:51 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
Nov 24 02:55:51 test001 mariadbd[453773]: 2022-11-24  2:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
```

But.. ‘Upgrade after a crash…’ why does it think there was a crash?

> FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK is useful if you want to take a backup of some tables. When FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK returns, all write access to tables are blocked and all tables are marked as 'properly closed' on disk. The tables can still be used for read operations.

So why does it think there was a crash?  Can I do something to make snapshots better so its not seen as a ‘Upgrade after crash’.  Or is there [easy] way to do accomplish what I”m trying to do?

I’ve tried using `FLUSH TABLES <list of all tables> FOR EXPORT` but it doesn’t seem to work on 5.5.56.

Answer (score 1):

`FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK` isn't enough to take a crash free snapshot. The reason is this sql doesn't stop the InnoDB flushing thread from applying previous writes.

The good positive is that the zfs snapshot is consistent.

So you need to briefly start the MariaDB-5.5 on the copy, then let it cleanly shutdown. And then you can continue with your 10.2+ version.

A userspace container manager like podman, run the `docker.io/library/mariadb:5.5` container with your datadir passed in as `-v /snapshot:/var/lib/mysql:Z` and stop (not kill) the container.